# My react application is not running and getting error

Tags: reactjs, npm

My react application is not running with npm start and getting high severity vulnerability. I tried npm audit fix --force but still not luck. Need help to understand how to fix it.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v14.6.0
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:436:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:434:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:350:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:264:13)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\kunal.vijan\react-app
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
8 verbose node v14.6.0
9 verbose npm  v6.14.6
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Make sure you are in the right project location (root path) to run `npm start`

Comment: You have to run npm scripts from the root directory where package.json is located

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using old version of node 14.x.. You should do following would help application up on `npm start`,

- Remove `node_module` folder
- Remove `package.lock.json` file.
- Check node version in you machine execute command `node -v`
- If it is not 16.x.x. execute `nvm use 16.15.1`
- Execute `npm install`
- Execute `npm start`